# Автоматическая отправка сообщения в чат с имитацией нажатия enter

Tags: javascript

здравствуйте, есть сайт с таким поллевом вода сообщений в чат.

```html
<form id="chatForm"><input class="form-control" placeholder="Type here to chat..." id="chatMessage" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off" type="text"></form>
```

Мне нужно что бы при входе на сайт отправлялось сообщение от меня в чат. Без перезагрузки страницы. Т.к. при отправки сообщения потом ещё нужно нажать кнопочку ок. В качестве подтверждения отправки. Т.е. отправка формы по средством sumbit. Не идёт. Потому что после самбит страница сразу перезагружается.

А если писать вручную сообщение и нажать enter сообщение отправляется и страница не перезагружается. Сразу скажу сайт не мой. Хочу сделать расширение.

Так я заполняю поле для отправки

```js
document.getElementById('chatMessage').value = 'Сообщение';
```

И нужно автоматизировать отправку.

Как можно реализовать отправку сообщения для этого поля имитацией нажатия кнопки enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошо бы увидеть форму, но предположительно так:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('chatMessage');

  input.value = 'Сообщение';
      
  var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true,
    'which': 13
  });
  input.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="chatMessage" onKeydown="alert('Clicked!')">
</form>
```

Comment: На странцие нету кнопки отправить сообщения, там есть только поле ввода, и отправлять сообщения только по нажатию enter, поэтому я хочу имитировать как то нажатие клавиши enter

Comment: Тоже не проблема. Изменил ответ.

Comment: csgodouble.com
Вот собственно сайт, сообщение почему то не отправляет, все еще не доходит до меня, консоль выдает true и более ничего

Comment: Отправка происходит не по enter'у в input'е, а по событию submit'а формы. Поэтому `KeyboardEvent('keydown')` надо заменить на `Event('submit')`, параметр `which` убрать и `dispatchEvent(event)` вызывать для формы.

Comment: `var input = document.getElementById('chatMessage');

  input.value = 'Сообщение';
      
  var event = new Event('submit', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  form.dispatchEvent(event);`

Простите, я не могу понять, я только учусь, но эта функция для меня очень нужна((

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/TheDeadOne/xypctL03/

Comment: Спасибо большоеееееее, все работает вы мне очень помогли, я вам очень благодарен